Adding a spout to kettle makes the subdiv bumpy
I tried to use the shrinkwrap modifier to make the verts snap to a smooth version of the kettle but that didn't fix it. I also added an extra edge running right under the spout but that also didn't fix it. It made that side flatter instead. The kettle only has eight sides,  fyi. Any suggestions? Do I just need to subdivide the whole kettle more and add more polygons?
The model:


Hello could you please share your object?

@moonboots Added the model to my question.

I was able to improve the surface by adding just a bit more polygons.

I added more vertical loops, so it's now got 16 sides instead of 8.
I then attatched an 8-sided cylinder with a boolean modifier and cleaned up the resulting vertices a bit.
Then I added a shrinkwrap modifier with a vertex group that only included the closest vertices. I also played around the offset value, because for some reason the surface didn't quite follow the target object. Not sure why still.



Maybe try this topology.................

Result:


Is the area around the spout smooth if you observe the shadows? The kettle looks a bit flat at the bottom under the spout. Maybe if you apply LoopTools - Circle on the rim it will fix it.

I've edited my answer so that you see the result in Object mode
